# JTextFields looping in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, loops, arraylist, jtextfield

I have a simple JForm that has some text fields.The problem is, my evaluate() method is not cycling through the text fields as I expected.All I get is the first text fields, of getText() that are executed. I'm stuck in this. Help would be great. Here is the code. Also here is a screen capture of the program: https://www.dropbox.com/s/w5ie4dfnc9wi216/Capture.JPG?dl=0

```
public MAppGest() {
    initComponents();
}

public double a=2.6;
public double index0;
public Iterator itr;

public void getText(String ind, String inde){
    evaluate();
    index0=Double.parseDouble(txtNewIndex.getText())-Double.parseDouble(txtOldIndex.getText());
    txtTotalIndex.setText(Double.toString(index0));
    txtRoom1.setText(Double.toString(index0));
    txtTotal1.setText(Double.toString((index0*a)));
} 

public void evaluate(){
    if(Boolean.valueOf(txtNewIndex.getText())&&Boolean.valueOf(txtOldIndex.getText())==true){
        getArray();
    } 
    else if(Boolean.valueOf(txtNewIndex2.getText())&&Boolean.valueOf(txtOldIndex2.getText())==true){
        getArray();
    }
    else if(Boolean.valueOf(txtNewIndex3.getText())&&Boolean.valueOf(txtOldIndex3.getText())==true){
        getArray();
    }
    else if(Boolean.valueOf(txtOldIndex4.getText())&&Boolean.valueOf(txOldIndex4.getText())==true){
        getArray();
    }
    else if(Boolean.valueOf(txtNewIndex5.getText())&&Boolean.valueOf(txtOldIndex5.getTex())==true){
        getArray();
    }
    else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(MAppGest.this,"An error occured");
    }
}

public void getArray() {
    ArrayList<String> al=new ArrayList<>();
    al.add(txtNewIndex.getText());
    al.add(txtOldIndex.getText());
    al.add(txtNewIndex2.getText());
    al.add(txtOldIndex2.getText());
    al.add(txtNewIndex3.getText());
    al.add(txtOldIndex3.getText());
    al.add(txtOldIndex4.getText());
    al.add(txOldIndex4.getText());
    al.add(txtNewIndex5.getText());
    al.add(txtOldIndex5.getText());

    for (int i = 0; i< al.size(); i++) {
        String fields []=null;
        fields[i] = al.get(i);
    }
}


private void btnGrandTotalActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    getText(txtNewIndex.getText(),txtOldIndex.getText());
    getText(txtNewIndex2.getText(),txtOldIndex2.getText()); 
    getText(txtNewIndex3.getText(),txtOldIndex3.getText());
    getText(txtOldIndex4.getText(),txOldIndex4.getText());
    getText(txtNewIndex5.getText(),txtOldIndex5.getText());    
}
```

Comment: [Boolean.valueOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#valueOf(java.lang.String))

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) *"I have a simple JForm that has some text fields"* Do you have a question?  Note also that their is no `JForm` class, please stop talking like your IDE & use the correct names for J2SE classes.

Comment: Ok, I'll have that in mind, when I'll post. I think I have found my error. My evaluate method isn't doing what it supposed to do.

Answer (score 2):

If your problem is that `evaluate()` is only completing the first `if` statement, it's because you are using `if-else` statements when you want to just use `if`. If you use `if-else`, once the first `if` is verified true it will skip the rest. If my answer is not what you are looking for, then I advise you to [ask a better question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Like the comments have said, give an SSCCE so the answerers aren't left guessing.

A side note: `Boolean.valueOf()` returns a boolean, so your `==true` is unnecessary.